# General solution and particular integral of $\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{y \sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)} = \text{constant}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the general solution of this equation. I tried separation of variable but it does not work because we have $y$ collaborated with $x$ terms: 
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} + \dfrac{y \sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)} = \text{constant}.$$

Also how would you find a particular solution which satisfies $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=1$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First_order_equation

Comment: It's a linear differential equation with $Q(x)=constant$

Answer (score 2):

Let that constant to be $C$. So you have $$y'+P(x)y=C$$ where $P(x)=\frac{ \sin x}{1+\cos x}$. Now set the function $\mu(x)=\exp(\int P(x)dx)$, multiply it to the ODE and then find a total differentail. An integration will lead you to have the 1 parameter family of solutions.

Comment: @RickyRozay: Ya! It is

Comment: then, you have $\frac{1}{1+cos(x)}y = \int \frac{C}{1+cos(x)} dx$ ? How can I solve the RHS?

Comment: $t=\tan(x/2)$...

Comment: @BabakS.: very nice + 1

Comment: I agree with Amzoti: good work +1

Answer (score 1):

$$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$$
Has a general solution . $$y\times e^{\int P(x).dx}=\int \Big[ Q(x)\times e^{\int P(x).dx}\Big].dx$$
So, now you ca solve. Where Q(x)=constant

Comment: then, you have $\frac{1}{1+cos(x)}y = \int \frac{C}{1+cos(x)} dx$ how you suppose to solve that with the constant on top?

Comment: $\int c.f(x).dx=c\times \int f(x).dx$. Note this. now it can be dne.

Comment: @RickyRozay after that use $cosx=\dfrac{1-tan^2x/2}{1+tan^2x/2}$ and put $tan(x/2)=t$

Comment: @RickyRozay which standard are u in?

Comment: @RickyRozay Particular solution is just to get rid of the integration constant by satisfying the given point.

Comment: @RickyRozay not the C you have defined as $Q(x)$ but a extra $c'$ you get after the integration.Constant of integration.

Comment: I don't know how u got that but it will be like $y=h(x)+k$ where $k=c.c'$ , $c'$ being constant of integration. which is followed by any indefinite integral. Now use y=0 if x=0.and find k

Comment: What are u talking of? y=h(x)+k means y is a function of x + a constant. you have found the function by integration(though not correct according to me). and now use y=0 when u put x=0. to get k.

Comment: @RickyRozay  Which standard are u in? I think it's par your understanding and u are solving a problem of a higher course than u have studied. Plz. leave it if this is the case.

Comment: @exploringnet: I admire your patience helping Ricky. +1